# Get a single text value using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this line to return a value, but instead its getting a True

```
var valor = valoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa.Select(p => p.Key == propiedad.Nombre).First();
```

This the view data passes from the controller

var valoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa = (Dictionary)ViewData["ValoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa"];

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            var listFields = from b in db.Propiedades
                             where b.Entidad.Nombre == "Empresa"
                             select b;
            ViewData["CamposAdicionalesEmpresa"] = listFields.ToList<Propiedad>();

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Empresa empresa = db.Empresas.Find(id);
            if (empresa.PropiedadesExtra != null)
            {
                XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(empresa.PropiedadesExtra);
                Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var el in xmlTree.Elements())
                {
                    dict.Add(el.Name.LocalName, el.Value);
                }

                ViewData["ValoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa"] = dict;
            }

            if (empresa == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(empresa);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `Select` to be a `Where`.  `Where` uses a predicate to filter the data and return the same structure...just a subset. `Select` on the other hand changes the data structure to be whatever is evaluated in the provided function. In your case you are changing the structure to be a single `Boolean` result equivalent to whether `Key` equals `Nombre`. The fixed code is below:

```
var valor = valoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa.Where(p => p.Key == propiedad.Nombre).First();
```

And, as pointed out in the comments, `First`* accepts a predicate itself, so you can simply call `First` as a combined `Where` and `First`

```
var valor = valoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa.First(p => p.Key == propiedad.Nombre);
```

`First` will throw if there is nothing, so you can use `FirstOrDefault` if that fits better

Comment: Correct but First takes the same condition of Where

Comment: @Steve Agreed, amended!

Answer (score 4):

In that case, `FirstOrDefault` is what you want:

```
var valor = valoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == propiedad.Nombre);
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs to be .Where(), not .Select(). .Select() returns the result of the expression, which is a boolean. .Where() returns the result where the expression is true.

Answer (score 1):

use `.FirstOrDefault()` and wouldnt hurt to be a bit more explicit in the declaring.

`string? valor = valoresCampoAdicionalesEmpresa.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == propiedad.Nombre);`